# jQuery function in directive not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My jQuery function isn't working inside my directive.

This is my directive:

```
app.directive('responsiveNav', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (element) {
          var pull = $('#pull');
          var menu = $('.nav-bar ul ul');
          var menuHeight = menu.height();

          $(pull).on('click', function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              menu.slideToggle();
          });

          $(window).resize(function () {
              var w = $(window).width();
              if (w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                  menu.removeAttr('style');
              }
          });
      }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header" responsive-nav>
        <div class="nav-bar">
            <ul style="padding:15 0 15 0;height:50px;">
                <li style="border-right: none;">
                    <a href="" style="padding:0;"><img src="assets/images/who-logo.png"></a>
                </li>
                <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
                <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;padding:8.5 0 8.5 0;">
                    <li><a class="active" href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Tickets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Event</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Video</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                    <li style="border-right: none;"><a><i class="fa fa-facebook" style="font-size: 1.5em;"></i></a></li>
                    <li style="border-right: none;"><a><i class="fa fa-instagram" style="font-size: 1.5em;"></i></a></li>
                    <li style="border-right: none;"><a><i class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size: 1.5em;"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
```

The directive doesn't even react to the click on `#pull` and I have no errors in my console. Hope you understand the problem. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Have you tried to use `angular.element` or consider the `element` in the link function?

Comment: No, where do I have to use it?

Comment: In the directive, you have a link function, and you pass a variable called `element`. Google what the element is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your directive is restricted to Element by

```
 restrict: 'E'
```

But you have put the directive as an attribute.

```
<div class="header" responsive-nav>
```

`restrict: 'A'` is one way to solve the problem.

Also I don't agree some of the ways you are using jquery here. Try to be angular as much as possible.

Please take some time to refer the [angular directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to make better use of this powerful feature of the framework.

Comment: Ahhhhh now I finally understand that part, but I got an error now `$ is not defined`.

Comment: That is because you have not included the jquery script in your index file.

Comment: Jup, I got that everything works fine now thanks a lot!

Comment: You can do this without JQuery library. Angular has jqlite by default. Try to follow it for practice. Also follow all the examples in the angular directive documentation.